# Why do some Jews name their sons Abram?

Tags: abraham

When God changed Abram's name to Abraham, it was a promotion of sorts:

> And you shall no longer be called Abram, but your name shall be Abraham, for I make you the father of a multitude of nations.  I will make you exceedingly fertile, and make nations of you; and kings shall come forth from you. I will maintain My covenant between Me and you, and your offspring to come, as an everlasting covenant throughout the ages, to be God to you and to your offspring to come. [Gen. 17:5-7]

So how come many Jews name their sons Abram instead of Abraham?  (I know some, but I don't know of a Jewish woman named Sarai.)

Comment: I know someone named Sarai. But I've never heard of someone named Avram. Still, in my understanding, the names didn't lose their meanings, just because Avraham and Sarah stopped using them. Sarai still means our lady or princess and Avram means literally great father and more symbolically, at shortening of father of Aram. So presumably, some people chose those names because they liked them more.

Comment: @Mauricemizrahi refer to the Zohar 1:93a which makes the question even stronger - According to the Zohar, Hashem only called him by the name Avraham once he had bris milah, then the letter 'hei' was added and the Shechina dwelt within him https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.93a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: As far as I know, *Avram* is basically a nickname for somenone named Avraham. It is not really the actual name.

Comment: I'm not sure we can objectively answer why some people do some thing. Do you mean to ask if there is any particular Jewish reason to name someone Abram?

Comment: Brachos 13a poses an even bigger problem: כל הקורא לאברהם אברם עובר בעשה

Comment: @talmid. More than that: Akedat Yitzhak says: "The new name of Abraham, embodying far greater blessings than the ones promised while he had still been uncircumcised, make the previous name pale by comparison, and reference to Abraham by his previous name is therefore tantamount to denial of his role in history."

Comment: my niece is named emunah sarai...

Comment: @talmidforlife Is there any reason to think that that refers to anything other than calling Abraham the Patriarch as Abram after his name was changed?